# Manage Localized Resources Via Visual Studio In A Plugin Library Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization

I am trying to end up being able to include satellite resources with a "Plugin" component, developed in C# and distributed as a DLL. It runs in a "Host" platform, and there are certain restrictions on how I can build and distribute.

I am using Visual Studio, and would like to figure out how to leverage the standard localization features: component-specific resources for my Forms, and other plugin-wide resources. Please bear with some explanation:

The Visual Studio aspect is set up this way: the platform delivers a VS project that is the host project for all of its Plugins. I develop my Plugin by using this project in VS. The Host also has an embedded code editor and other development tools. The Plugin C# code resides in a Host source folder.

Distributing the Plugin requires a compilation from the Host; and then using Host tools to export my plugin files as a DLL. The host compiles the Plugin source against all other default Plugins, then does code obfuscation, and generates stub files for execution, and also manifest-type files. This is all bundled into a Zip file and that's the distribution assembly for the Plugin. When the user installs the Plugin, this is all actually unZipped into the user's Host folder.

[image: File Setup]

I am trying to use Localization features: I cannot simply localize my forms in VS, since the resources are embedded into the VS build output, which is not bundled with the Host Plugin; and is not accessible for me to include at distribution. Also, the Host does not allow me to select the resx files when it does my build for distribution (that might have solved it; but the "Export Plugin" dialog in the Host only allows selecting the C# files that you want to bundle into a distributable Plugin).

I am aware of the ability to bundle resources into a DLL; and I believe that would be my preferred solution if it is possible; and then perhaps I could use the IDE features, then select all my resource files and generate a satellite assembly with the resources. But I cannot figure out how to reference the resources. This would result in satellite resource DLLs placed alongside the MyPlugin.dll (or in culture subfolders) as pictured above. The Host platform allows including dependent DLLs with your Plugin; and they would be unpacked alongside the MyPlugin.dll as pictured.

I have tried simply running AL, and generating a satellite assembly with resources; and placing that file in the Host folder; and also in culture subfolders. However, the resource loading is failing: it does not find the resources.

I have also tried adding the:
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
in my Plugin source file; and that did not help.

Can anyone figure this out enough to advise me? It may be a namespace problem; which I do not understand well enough to code for. If I have to change the way resources are loaded, I would do that also; but I do not understand enough about the way the resources are managed to know where to begin at this point.

Even given an explanation about what's under the hood with the resources and files, I may figure something out: but I am just looking at the IDE features, and hoping to use them and just find out how to successfully bundle and include the resources along with the Plugin DLL. I don't understand enough about what's under the hood.

Comment: What exactly is the 'Host tools' you refer to? if that is vs, then satellites should be created. If it's not, you just might to have to bundle all translations into one resx (neutral) and then pick it with some algorithm, e.g. prefix all with de-de or en-us or something, but that is a really bad idea.

Comment: It is not VS. And I agree that one fat resource file would be a bad idea. I think you understand the problem: I need to somehow end up with satellite resources that the Plugin.dll will successfully reference at runtime; but I am failing at it so far. I have also made one attempt at the [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)] attribute, but that failed so far as well.

Comment: Assuming your .csproj is a library template, can you build it in VS locally, then send the files to whatever it is to compile, and then drop the en-us etc. folders next to the plugin? Make sure to change the versioning to become static (e.g. not 1.0.*.*) so that the versions are the same and make sure that if the end resulting .dll is strongly named (signed) you do the same on your end when generating satellites. If the whole app is .net these should be loaded.

Comment: Thank you zaitsman. I am giving up on the satellite attempt. Instead, for now, I'm loading the resources manually from .resources files; and I can use the IDE's resource editors and all of that.. I do use the IDE tools for localization; and then in the strongly-named .cs files that it auto-generates, I run a post-build script that replaces the ResourceManager constructor with a call to CreateFileBasedResourcemanager --- and I execute ResGen and include the .resources file. I appreciate the help: I keep trying satellites but I can't get them to load ... perhaps I'll eventually figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... I wound up solving this just by loading resources myself manually ... Explained here:

[Building Resource-Only DLL (With al.exe) Is Raising "assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729410/building-resource-only-dll-with-al-exe-is-raising-assembly-is-built-by-a-runt)