# Building Resource-Only DLL (With al.exe) Is Raising "assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime"

Tags: .net, localization

I am packaging resources; and I am successfully loading them from .resource files using ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager. I want to instead create dll files with the resources, and load those with Assembly.LoadFrom; and then load the resources with new ResourceManager(string, Assembly). When I do this, I am getting:

**"assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime".**

The project is a class library; and it is distributed and run inside of a "host" like a "plugin". The host is running .Net 3.5. My VS project is configured to target 3.5 ... and I am actually running al.exe manually to build the DLL.

I can run a test Program in my project (also set to target 3.5) and my code will load the Assembly (and find resources). But when the same code runs in the "host", I get the error.

I have tried every version of al.exe that I can find on my machine; and I specifically downloaded the .NET 3.5 SDK; which seemed to install into C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0 but I always get the error no matter which version of al.exe I run.

Can someone help me build the dll so that it will load inside of this .NET 3.5 environment? --- Again it's a resource-only DLL. These are the post-build commands:

```
ResGen.exe AdResources.resx AdResources.resources
al.exe /target:lib /embed:AdResources.resources /culture:en /out:AdResources.resources.dll
```

The .cs code I use to load the Assembly and resources is like this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(InstallDir, "AdResources.resources.dll");
Assembly resAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
ResourceManager temp = new ResourceManager("AdResources", resAssembly);
```

... Works when run in the IDE (targeting 3.5) but fails in the end host platform.

Comment: There's very little evidence from your snippet that you are running the correct version of al.exe.  Diagnose with ildasm.exe, double click the manifest and look at the first line.  Surely it now says // Metadata version: v4.0.30319.  Wrong version.  You must use the v2 version of al.exe, whichever it is, you didn't mention your VS version.

Comment: THANKS Hans. I HAVE been looking for the v2 version of al.exe. I do not think I have found it. The VS version is Community 2015 RC. I was able to download the .NET 3.5 SDK: but that version of al.exe didn't work. I can see the .NET folder in: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 but it doesn't have an al.exe (is this runtime only?) I am about to try using csc ...

Comment: Sigh, you can't do a professional programmer's job with tools made for an amateur.  Microsoft gives free software away because they know you'll need the full version sooner or later.  It is sooner.

Comment: I am still failing: I just used csc in the above v2.0.50727 directory, the load fails with the same message (but succeeds when run in the IDE). ildasm reports: // Metadata version: v2.0.50727

Comment: Are you implying the Professional IDE will perform the build correctly? It seems impossible since I'm doing the build manually ... what am I missing? I still have a trial of the Professional IDE on another machine. I will see if that is working. I think I also have access from Asure.net; but it's 32-bit only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

Despite Hans' comments, I solved it by USING the IDE (Community 2015 RC).

I created a new class library project. Set the target to .NET 3.5 --- and made sure the App.config said the same thing. Then I copy my .resx files (only) from my main project into this project. I removed the custom tool (that generates the strong names). And the output that the IDE builds will load just fine in my host environment!

So, very odd that I can use the IDE but not the tools, even when I use the 3.5 or 2.0 tools directly; and verify that the output manifest does say "// Metadata version: v2.0.50727"!

I created a Pre-Build script to copy my resx files from the main project; and a Post-Build script to copy this library into my target output folder. Working fine ...

Comment: ... I just re-read this answer, and just want to be sure it doesn't sound like I was negative towards Hans's comment --- just the opposite. It's still strange why I can't load the libraries created with the tools directly (including csc version 2; and also al version 3.5); yet a library created by the IDE with the target set to 3.5 WILL load ...